# ArrayList Skip Data when Show?

Tags: android, arrays

**UPDATE SOLVED :**

i don't know what happened, my Array is work normally when i add this code :

```
EditText editText= new EditText(this);
editText.setId(456 + i);
mSurveyView.addView(editText);
```

---

I don't know how to title this question. Because i am confused, but i will explain my problem with code

So, I have ArrayList data, ex : 1 2 3 4 5 , but when i try to show/debug just get 3 data like 1 3 5. I think, the ArrayList skip my data?

**This is my code :**

```
if (dataSurvey.listFieldSurvey.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataSurvey.listFieldSurvey.size(); i++) {
                FieldSurvey xx = dataSurvey.listFieldSurvey.get(i);
                String type = xx.metaSurvey.name;

                Log.d("Tag", "type text " + dataSurvey.listFieldSurvey.size());

                labelCaption = new TextView(getActivity());
                labelCaption.setId(456 + i);
                labelCaption.setText(xx.name + ". " + xx.caption);
                labelCaption.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

                mSurveyView.addView(labelCaption);

            }


        }
```

I tried Log.d "Tag", i have data size 5, but just show 3 data when i tried to show

Comment: you have printed size of List not elements.

Comment: paste you log pls

Comment: Log.d("Tag", "type text " + dataSurvey.listFieldSurvey.size()); this will always print the Size of your arrayList

Comment: The code is looking okey. what function or command outside the `if` condition?

Comment: @Fr099y the function `if` condition is nothing if i hide, still not work my array

Comment: @xbadal my code now work normally, check my update. i dont know why

Comment: Maybe you should `labelCaption = new TextView(getActivity());` change to `TextView labelCaption = new TextView(getActivity());`